# Calculating Uncertainty with Mean Absolute Deviation

Tags: measurements

I'm taking an Introductory Physics course and, when learning about approximating uncertainty, I was wondering if a more quantitative method would be to calculate the Mean Absolute Deviation using the data? The way I learned in the past was to estimate the uncertainty by the size of the units of the instrument being used. If using the Mean Absolute Deviation isn't a better way, why not?